# Android java Listview scroll automatic a slow time

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with some elements, I have to make this list scroll automatically, with a slow scroll.

When he reaches the last element he stops.

If new items are added in the queue, then the listview must restart, until it reaches the last element again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Still _ListView_? Use `RecyclerView` for better performance.

Comment: add your code and also used listview instand of recyclerview. recyclerview it is latest.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, thought your adapter implemented in effective way. so this code is just scrolls listview

you need to try another values of variables

```
final long totalScrollTime = Long.MAX_VALUE; //total scroll time. I think that 300 000 000 years is close enouth to infinity. if not enought you can restart timer in onFinish()

final int scrollPeriod = 20; // every 20 ms scoll will happened. smaller values for smoother

final int heightToScroll = 20; // will be scrolled to 20 px every time. smaller values for smoother scrolling

listView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                new CountDownTimer(totalScrollTime, scrollPeriod ) {
                                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                        listView.scrollBy(0, heightToScroll);
                                    }

                                public void onFinish() {
                                    //you can add code for restarting timer here
                                }
                            }.start();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: It seems to work, but strange things happen.

I'll explain I have 21 items.
The elements 20,19,18,17 flow exclusively.
All others do not appear in scrolling.


  Another problem is that being that they make a listView.scrollBy when the last items arrive they disappear.
The thing I would like to do is block it, do not let it flow anymore until there are no other elements.
Something like this: https://i.imgur.com/NXDjShM.jpg

Comment: you can check the last visible item of listView and interrupt the timer to stop Scrolling and if you want infinite scroll the you can restart it. and also read the comments in code for better implementation.

Comment: But it does not solve at the moment because only 4 elements of 21 flow.
I also tried to use: listView.setSelection (adapter.getCount () - 1);
But it does not work.

Comment: In the meantime I'm trying to think if we can add the following feature: https://pastebin.com/QiiXtgT2
That when I go up the listview it stops, if I go down she continues.
But it seems that it does not work properly or I'm wrong maybe something.

Answer (score 0):

use the below method to scroll your listview. for example:

```
scrollMyTableView(activityListview,11,0,getTotalHeightofListView(activityListview),0);
```

method:

```
private void scrollMyTableView(View v,final int var, int fromY, int toY, int delay){

    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(v, "scrollY", fromY, toY).setDuration(2000);
    objectAnimator.setStartDelay(delay);
    objectAnimator.start();
    objectAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
    });
}
```

and if new item added to adapter and need to again go to top of listview and again come back to bottom.you can use below code to do this:

```
myAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                activityListview.setSelection(0);
scrollMyTableView(activityListview,11,0,getTotalHeightofListView(activityListview),0);
            }
        });
```

To calculate the height of listview use below method

```
public int getTotalHeightofListView(ListView listView) {

        ListAdapter mAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

        int totalHeight = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View mView = mAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

            mView.measure(
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),

                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

            totalHeight += mView.getMeasuredHeight();

        }
        return totalHeight;

    }
```

Comment: I tried the code, it does not seem to work properly.
I also tried to replace: ListAdapter mAdapter = listView.getAdapter ();
Directly with the adapter I use in the listview, nothing changes.
In the video, I used the solution with: ListAdapter mAdapter = listView.getAdapter ();
scrollMyTableView (listView, 11, 0, getTotalHeightofListView (listView), 10000);
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt (v, "scrollY", fromY, toY) .setDuration (8000);

Comment: Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EKrU_3DeMdpzMR61z1zyPsxaDan0xjpv/view

In the first part of the videos you can see, what I'm trying to achieve.
The number of elements in the list are 21, [0-20].
As you can see from the video appear only 4 items from 20 to 17.
If you pay attention you can see that the scroll in this case drops.
As you can see if I click on the elements, all of them appear at the beginning of the element head 20.

Comment: In the second part of the video the one on Youtube is what I would like to implement as a solution.
There are a series of messages, elements of the listview.
If I get on top I can see the old messages, if in the meantime are added new messages in the queue nothing happens, because I climbed up to see the old ones.

If instead I redeem, then until the last element of the list and in the meantime that I am at the end, are added new messages in the listview the list scrolls. Minute [1.11-1.5] at the end of the video.

Comment: I have seen the video. The above code can give exactly the solution of your problem. I have already implemented in my project. you need to just change according to your project code.

Comment: It would be possible to see I do not know the video of what you have implemented in your project to understand how you did?
Or some portion of code?
These are days that I look for solutions, for how to solve these problems.

Comment: I'm doing several attempts, but I do not understand why when you scroll you see only the first 4 elements, the others are invisible.

Comment: it is because of calculating height if listview. you change height of listview  in scrollMyTableView(activityListview,11,0,getTotalHeightofListView(activityListview),0);. according to your requirenment.

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm not understanding what you would say?

Answer (score 0):

Use listview `smoothScrollToPosition(int position)` function.

Please have a look on this post also
https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.widget.ListView/smoothScrollToPosition